# Problem with Quick Sort Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I'm working on a quick sort algorithm in C#, but I'm facing a strange problem which is, among 10 times of executing the algorithm on random numbers, I got 2 or 3 wrong sorting answers.

I mean: this code can sort about 7 out of 10 examples; why?  I couldn't figure out what's the problem, can you help me?

```
  public void quicksort(int[] data, int first, int n)
   { 
       int pivotIndex, n1, n2;
       if (n > 1)
       {
           pivotIndex= partition(data, first, n);
           n1 = pivotIndex-first;
           n2 = n -n1 -1;
           quicksort(data, first, n1);
           quicksort(data, pivotIndex+ 1, n2);
       }
   }

   private int partition(int[] data, int first, int n)
   {
       int t;
       int pivot= data[first], tooBigIndex=first+1, tooSmallIndex=first+n-1;
       while (tooBigIndex<= tooSmallIndex)
       {
        while( (tooBigIndex < n) && (data[tooBigIndex] <= pivot) )
                tooBigIndex++;
       while (data[tooSmallIndex] > pivot) 
            tooSmallIndex--;
           if (tooBigIndex< tooSmallIndex) 
           {
            t = data[tooBigIndex];
            data[tooBigIndex] = data[tooSmallIndex];
            data[tooSmallIndex] = t;
            tooSmallIndex--;
            tooBigIndex++;
           }
       }
       t= data[0];
       data[0]= data[tooSmallIndex] ;
       data[tooSmallIndex]=t;
       return tooSmallIndex;

   }
}
```

Comment: Do you always get the wrong sort on the same set of the random numbers? If yes, could you please post the set? Also, what is "int n" parameter in the quicksort(..) method?

Comment: int n, refers to the length of the array I'm working on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm astonished the code you posted **ever** works -- or even *terminates*.  The test:

```
(tooBigIndex < n) &&
```

should clearly be

```
(tooBigIndex < first + n) &&
```

and the index in the lines:

```
   t= data[0];
   data[0]= data[tooSmallIndex];
   data[tooSmallIndex]=t;
```

should be `first`, **not** `0` (making the first line useless, as you could omit it and use `pivot` in lieu of `t` in the third line -- but that's a redundancy, the other two are horrible bugs;-).

I *think* this is all the bugs, but I've only tested on random arrays;-).

Answer (score 3):

If this is a homework question, you should mark it as such so we can target the assistance better (more nudges in the right direction rather than outright solutions).

If it's not homework, you should consider using the IComparable interface with Array.sort(). For integers, which do provide the IComparable interface, you should be able to just use something like:

```
int[] valArray = new int[6] { 1, 5, 2, 6, 9, 7 };
Array.Sort (valArray);                            // <-- This is all you need.
String s = "";
foreach (int val in valArray)
    s += "," + val;
MessageBox.Show (s.Substring(1));
```

which results in:

```
1,2,5,6,7,9
```

and I'm pretty certain it uses QuickSort under the covers. Re-inventing the wheel is a bad idea, fine for educational purposes but, if the intent is (as you indicate) to just be able to sort an array, use the language-provided features and save yourself the effort.

Comment: This isn't a Homework, but I need the code for my own project.

Comment: Why? If you're using the C# language, use it. Don't re-invent the wheel, that's just crazy talk :-)

Comment: My project is about teaching sorting Algorithms.I'm not re-inventing anything. So, I need to make my own sort method which I can control where to paint and where to wait and so on.